# Dynamically adding select2 to DOM which gets data from DB

Tags: php, jquery-select2

I have a HTML table where user can choose products from MySql db.

I have a "add new row" possibility where new row is added to DOM.

Once I add new row, select-2 is no longer functioning in this new row - I beleive it is a problem, that it is searching for input only in first example of select-2 dropdown. How can I show dropdown for each instance?

Code:

```
<table id="add_new" style="width: 100%; margin-top:40px;" class="col-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xl-12">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left; font-size: 10px; color:#8f8f8f; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 10%;">
        Zap. št.: </th>
                <th style="text-align:left; font-size: 10px; color:#8f8f8f; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 50%;">
          Naziv artikla </th>
                <th style="text-align:left; font-size: 10px; color:#8f8f8f; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 20%;">
          Količina </th>
                <th style="text-align:right; font-size: 10px; color:#8f8f8f; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 20%;">
          EM (kos/m/colli,...) </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr id="mainsection">
              <td> <p href="#" id="count" style="font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none; line-height: 1; color:#909090; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0;">
          1</p> </td>
                <td contenteditable style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                  <h4 style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1; margin-bottom:0; color:#303030; font-weight:500; margin-top: 10px;">
                    <select class="form-control select2-multiple" id="dd_artikli" data-width="100%">
                            <option value="">Select country</option>
                            <?php
              if (count($itemRecords_artikli) > 0) {
                  foreach ($itemRecords_artikli as $ct) {
              ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $ct['id']; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $ct['name']; ?>
                                </option>
                            <?php
                  }
              }
              ?>
                        </select>
                      </h4>
                    </td>
                <td contenteditable> <p href="#" style="font-size: 13px; text-decoration: none; line-height: 1; color:#909090; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0;"> </p> </td>
                <td contenteditable style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0; text-align: right;"> <p style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 1; color:#303030; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:0; vertical-align:top; white-space:nowrap;"> </p> </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<script>
    var number = 1;
    document.getElementById("newsectionbtn").onclick = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById("add_new");
    var section = document.getElementById("mainsection");
    var count = document.getElementById('count');
    number++;
    count.textContent = number.toString();

    container.appendChild(section.cloneNode(true));
  }
  </script>

<

?php
/*
 @Author: Sanjay Kumar
 @Project: PHP MySQLi How To Use Select2 for Multiple Select Tutorial
 @Email: onlinewebtutorhub@gmail.com
 @Website: https://onlinewebtutorblog.com/
*/

// Include the database configuration file
require 'dbconfig.php';

$countrySelect = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM artikli");

$countrySelect->execute();
$countries = $countrySelect->get_result();

$itemRecords_artikli = array();
while ($item = $countries->fetch_assoc()) {
    extract($item);
    $itemDetails = array(
        "id" => $id,
        "name" => $naziv
    );
    array_push($itemRecords_artikli, $itemDetails);
}
?>
```

Comment: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Answer (score 0):

After drop-down bind run this command.

```
jQuery('#dd_artikli').select2();
```

Or use the jquery ready function.

`$(document).ready(function() { jQuery('#dd_artikli').select2(); });`

Comment: Where do you exactly mean "After drop-down bind"?

Comment: Mean when options are created then you need to rebind.